# How to form::select in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Since `form::select` has been deprecated, what is the new way to create a dropdown list in `form` containing `options` from database?

I went through Laravels documentation and could not find anything that replaces `form::select`.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form and html builder component has been removed from Laravel, but it is available under another package. You can include it with:

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

However, the alternative is to do it manually:

```
<select name="your_name">
    @foreach ($records as $row)
        <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```